# print the count and the value of selected options inside a text box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanted to make a script to parse the count of selected options from a dropdown list.
I tried my code to jsfiddle but it doesnt work, even if i dont get any syntax error.did i do something wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var count=$("#jform_params_foreignmanuf:selected").length;
                 $("#jform_params_manucounter").val(count);
              });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aewsduwo/22/ .

Also if i wanted to make a text area and print the value of the dropdown option?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $val= $("#jform_params_foreignmanuf:selected").val;
    $("#jform_params_manucounter").val($val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvpqd286/6/ i think this, for the first option in my example

```
<option selected="selected" value="127">1</option>
```

would ouput "127" instead of "1" that i want to print right?

Comment: remove "#" from select box ID attribute (jform_params_foreignmanuf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) You need to escape special character present in id tag.

2) You need to find option by selected attribute and not select element as selected

```
 $("#\\#jform_params_foreignmanuf :selected").length
```

**[Demo for selected option count](http://jsfiddle.net/tgqmx0gh/)**

and for getting selected elements value in textbox as comma seprated string:

```
 var count=$("#\\#jform_params_foreignmanuf").val().join(",");
 $("#jform_params_manucounter").val(count);
```

**[Demo for selected value](http://jsfiddle.net/bj0xxtdj/)**

**Update:** for getting first selected option text:

```
 var firstselectedtext=$("#\\#jform_params_foreignmanuf :Selected:first").text();
 $("#jform_params_manucounter").val(firstselectedtext);
```

**[Demo for first selected option text](http://jsfiddle.net/27qvunyn/)**

for getting all selected options text:

```
var selectedtext=$.map( $('#\\#jform_params_foreignmanuf :Selected'), function (element) { 
    return $(element).text() 
});
$("#jform_params_manucounter").val(selectedtext.join(','));
```

**[Demo for getting all selected options text](http://jsfiddle.net/bog8sc3g/)**

Comment: @IseNgaRt: it does..have a look at both the demo. first, you have not given space for `:selected` selector.second,you do not need to escape second elements selctor as it does not have special character in it.

Comment: Actually i didnt want the 127!
i need to parse this <option selected="selected" value="127">**1**</option> !

Comment: do you want text inside option element?

Comment: exactly ! i need the text because the list will contain names as text inside the option !

Comment: yeap but not for only the first but for every selected one. i need this  : http://jsfiddle.net/u9dvmytn/4/ ( without the join() it works properly ! )

Comment: Thanks you were really useful , i mark it as answered and i will ask one more question if u could answer: As your last code is really complex for someone like me that is newbie at jquery, couldnt we use this : $("#jform_params_manucounter").val(firstselectedtext.join(',')); because if i remore the .join it works fine. but with .join(',') it doesnt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66448/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-isengart).

Answer (score 1):

1. *if i wanted to make a text area and **print the value of the dropdown option**?*

Then you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $val = $('select[id="#jform_params_foreignmanuf"] :selected').text();
    $("#jform_params_manucounter").val($val);
});
```

As your select element contains a special character of `#` so either you can escape it with `\\` or you can make an attribute selector like above.

2. *would ouput "127" instead of "1" that i want to print right?*

For this you just need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

[Checkout the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/pvpqd286/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$("#jform_params_foreignmanuf").on('click', function(){
    var count = $("#jform_params_foreignmanuf option:selected").length; //count selected options
    $("#jform_params_manucounter").val(count);

    var val= [];
    $("#jform_params_foreignmanuf option:selected").each(function(){
        val.push($(this).text()); //save each selected text in array
    });
    $("#jform_params_manuvalue").text(val.join(',')); //write selected text to textarea (comma-seperated)
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sbhc51h/)**